# In what order are boolean expressions evaluated

Tags: c#, boolean-expression

I have been looking for an explanation for the order in which boolean expressions are evaluated but cannot find one.

Take a look at this statement :

```
if (locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && locRwF.PlaceID > -1 || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0)
```

How is this evaluated.
will it be like this :

```
if ((locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && locRwF.PlaceID > -1) || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0)
```

or like this :

```
if (locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && (locRwF.PlaceID > -1 || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0))
```

Is there some documentation about this I dont know the correct search term because english is not my language.

I know I can test it but I would like to find the documentation about this so I can fully understand it

Comment: As you've discovered from the answers, the term sought for is `precedence` -  but I'd also note that in almost all languages I can think of, extra brackets don't impose a performance penalty and so if you're at all unsure, just insert the brackets so that the expression is *clearly* doing what you intend it to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I always use brackets but I found this expression in somenones code today and wanted to be sure where to put the brackets in. Thanks

Comment: Indeed, use brackets. You should not only write code that somehow works, but also code that others can understand. If you add some brackets, at least the next person reading your code doesn't have to ask this same question. Refactoring the condition to a function may be even nicer to future programmers. And if you are the future programmer don't miss out on a chance to make things better :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: There are two schools of thought here and I'm from the other one. I think you should commit your precedence table to memory before you're out of nappies and *always* use the absolute minimum number of parentheses. Perhaps with the exception of the ternary conditional operator in PHP which has a bizarre reversal of associativity!

Comment: @oerkelens I fully agree. This is someone else code and I wanted to be sure where to put the brackets in

Comment: @Bathsheba terse code is fine, but complicated if-clauses are more readable as separate functions with a descriptive name. In that function you can even split the condition without needing brackets for readability :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so

```
locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && locRwF.PlaceID > -1 || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0
```

is evaluated as

```
(locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && locRwF.PlaceID > -1) || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0
```

Note that `&&` and `||` are also short-circuited so evaluation of the right-hand operand only occurs if that could change the result following the evaluation of the left-hand one.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The expression are readed from left to right in addition to that the `&&`  has higher precedence than `||`.
So in your case it's would be like

```
if ((locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1 && locRwF.PlaceID > -1) || locClsTanken.DagPrijs == 0)
```

And the technical therm that you're looking for is 
***Operators Precedence*** take a look to this [link:Operators Precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operators_precedence.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In C# the compiler moves from left to right, meaning it will evaluate the left most expression first (in your case that is `locClsTanken.PlaceID == -1`)

Also, `&&` has higher priority than `||` --> gets evaluated first

However, what might confuse you is how the compiler handels the `&&` and `||`. There is a difference between `&` and `&&`.

`&` means both expressions have to be true and both expressions are evaluated. However, `&&` only causes one expression to be evaluated first. If the first expression fails, then the second one isn't even evaluated, because in order for `&&` to be true both expressions need to be true. If the first one already fails `&&` is always false --> `&&` is faster than `&` and more "inteligent"